# Do we need to install SQL Server 2008 SP2 after installing SQL Server 2008 R2 RTM?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have installed [SQL Server 2008 R2 RTM (Express) with Management Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=23650). But I am confused, do I need to install [SQL Server 2008 (Express) Service Pack 2](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=20610)?

Is there SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no. If you just installed it, you it probably came with SP1 included: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=12847

Service Pack 2 is only for SQL Server 2008, not R2.

If you don't already have it, you should be able to get it with your Microsoft Updates automatically.